# Collision Issue Pinball VB.net 2015

Tags: vb.net, vector, picturebox, collision, detection

So I am making a basic pinball game using vb.net and am having an issue with the collisions that once the ball slows down a certain amount it glitches inside and then through the walls.

I am using a picturebox for the walls and the ball and am using the intersectwith(picturebox command to detect collision.

any help on how to fix this would be appreciated. Thanks

Bellow is most of the  code: (pctball is the ball)

```
 Private Sub Screen_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    DoubleBuffered = True
    dX = 6 ' Pixels per timer tick
    dY = 6

    Timer1.Enabled = True

    'array for colliding scores
    For Each obj In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf obj Is PictureBox AndAlso obj.tag = "Disc" Then
            DiscArray(i) = obj
            i += 1
        End If
    Next


End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    If GameActive = True Then

        Labelx.Text = PctBall.Left
        Labely.Text = PctBall.Top

        PctBall.Left = PctBall.Left + dX
        PctBall.Top = PctBall.Top + dY

        ' check for ball hitting edges, reverse direction if so
        If PctBall.Left < 10 Or PctBall.Left > MyBase.Width - PctBall.Width Then
            dX = -dX
        End If

        If PctBall.Top < 10 Then
            dY = -dY
        End If

        If LeftFlipper = True Then
            FlipperDefaultL.Visible = False
            FlipperUpL.Visible = True
        Else
            FlipperDefaultL.Visible = True
            FlipperUpL.Visible = False
        End If

        If RightFlipper = True Then
            FlipperDefaultR.Visible = False
            FlipperUpR.Visible = True
        Else
            FlipperDefaultR.Visible = True
            FlipperUpR.Visible = False
        End If

        GravityFunction()

        ReboundAngle()


        ' If ball goes outside bottom
        If PctBall.Bottom > MyBase.Height Then
            GameActive = False
            Game_Over()
        End If


    End If


End Sub
Private Sub Keys_Down(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    Select Case e.KeyValue
        Case Keys.Space
            GameActive = True
        Case Keys.D
            LeftFlipper = True
        Case Keys.K
            RightFlipper = True

    End Select

End Sub

Private Sub Keys_Up(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyUp
    Select Case e.KeyValue
        'Case Keys.Space
        '    GameActive = False
        Case Keys.D
            LeftFlipper = False
        Case Keys.K
            RightFlipper = False

    End Select
End Sub

Private Sub GravityFunction()
    ' gravity
    gravity = CollisionCount
    dY += gravity
    PctBall.Top += dY

End Sub

Private Function CheckCollision()

    For Each PictureBox In Me.Controls
        If PictureBox IsNot PctBall AndAlso PictureBox.visible = True AndAlso PctBall.Bounds.IntersectsWith(PictureBox.Bounds) Then
            collision = True
            CollisionCount += 0.1
            For discCount = 0 To DiscArray.Length - 1
                If PictureBox IsNot PctBall AndAlso PctBall.Bounds.IntersectsWith(DiscArray(discCount).Bounds) Then
                    score = score + 1
                    ScoreBoard.scorelabel.Text = "Score: " & score
                End If
            Next
            Exit For 'Exit when at least one collision found 
        Else : collision = False
        End If
    Next

    If Collision = True Then
        Coll.Text = "True"
    Else
        Coll.Text = "False"
    End If
    Return collision

End Function

Private Function ReboundAngle()

    If CheckCollision() Then
        dX = -dX
        dY = -dY
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: If you set breakpoints it would help to narrow down to where the problem exist. **Can you tell us where the problem is?** There are more than a few issue I can see, but this is not code review either... Would the issue possibly reside in `CheckCollision`?

Comment: Yes, the problem would appear to be related with either how it checks collisions or how it rebounds after the collision is detected. But I'm not sure specifically, the collision checking works but as the ball looses momentum it is sucked inside the picturebox walls and then forced out the other side.